# tensorflow work function with data

Tags: tensorflow

I have a question. For example, I have an array and want to change their boundary values. I want to write a function that changes these values. I get an array to this function.
The question is does these function link to these array or copy it?

Best regards,
Elijah.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Values of nodes are immutable. Only variables can be modified.

If you have an operation that changes some of the values it will produce a different array.

It's not specified if it's modified in place or first copied and then modified. That is implementation dependent.

Comment: Thank you for answer! Ii is very useful!